# How can I get all view scope managed beans for the current ViewRoot?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, view-scope

I have to implement some bean post processor for all view scope managed beans on the page. I have implemented `SystemEventListener` with `PostConstructViewMapEvent` as system-event-class. How can I get all view scope managed beans for the current ViewRoot? `viewRoot.getViewMap()` returns empty map (Mojarra JSF 2.1.19), but I have a few managed beans with view scope. Of course I can invoke my post processor in @PostConstruct method in every such bean, but is there a global solution like in Spring Framework?

My faces-config.xml configuration:

```
<application>
        <system-event-listener>
            <system-event-listener-class>com.myapplicationname.ViewScopeBeanPostProcessor</system-event-listener-class>
            <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PostConstructViewMapEvent</system-event-class>
            <source-class>javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot</source-class>
        </system-event-listener>
    </application>
```

Comment: To be sure: JSF or CDI managed beans? (do note that Spring bean management facility is in no way comparable to JSF's one, but more to CDI's one). As to your attempt with the event listener, that event is basically fired directly after `new ViewMap()`, so it's obviously empty.

Comment: @BalusC JSF managed beans. I tried to use `PreRenderViewEvent`, but also unsuccesfully.